# lightning button dynamic component rendering in google chrome

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

When I try to create dynamic lightning button it is not displaying in google chrome.But it is displaying firefox.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
     <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }"/>
     <div aura:id="buttonrender"></div> 
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.createComponent(
            "lightning:button",
            {
                "aura:id": "findableAuraId",
                "label": "Press Me",
                "onclick": component.getReference("c.handlePress")
            },
            function(newButton){
                    var body = component.find("buttonrender").get("v.body");
                    body.push(newButton);
                    component.set("v.body", body);
            }
        );
    },
    handlePress : function(component, event, helper) {
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your code works on Chrome.

In fact, there's an error at this line: `component.set("v.body", body);`

You don't have an attribute called `body` in your component.

You have two ways to add the button dynamically.

1. The first one would be to add `buttons` attribute to your component.
   Then, you only have to get the current value of this attribute, push
   the new button and finally replace the old value with the new one.
   Using the below code:

---

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
     <aura:attribute name="buttons" type="Aura.Component[]" />
     <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }"/>
     {!v.buttons}
</aura:component>
```

---

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.createComponent(
            "lightning:button",
            {
                "aura:id": "findableAuraId",
                "label": "Press Me",
                "onclick": component.getReference("c.handlePress")
            },
            function(newButton){
                var body = component.get("v.buttons");
                body.push(newButton);
                component.set("v.buttons", body);
            }
        );
    },
```

2. The second one would be to use your current code. But you should replace the use of the `body` attribute by selecting your `div` first, then updating its `body`. Using the below code:

   `component.find("buttonrender").set("v.body", body);`

Comment: In my opinion it is not recommended to define an attribute named body by yourself as it will be conflicting with the one available in every aura:component by default

Comment: @ChristianMenzinger You're totally right. Looks like I answered without thinking hard enough... Thank you for your warning. I updated the answer.